# Maps are not being render correctly in Android emulator

Tags: google-maps, android-emulator

I used Android Maps in my app and the Android Emulator since years ago. For some reason I cannot tell, the Maps are not being displayed correctly. This started to happen about 2 months ago after some updated. It seems like many times something gets broken after upgrading.
It works correctly in real devices, though.

[image]

As you can see in the image, only names are being written. The land or the sea are gone. And what is more important for me (for debugging purposes) is that the **Markers** I add are not displayed either.

By the way, the Google Maps app is being displayed correctly. Only my app fails to display maps.

Comment: Did you got any solution to this issue?

Comment: No, sorry. I didn't. Do you have same problem? I am glad I am not the only one.

Comment: Yes, me too facing the same issue after updating android sdk tools.

Answer (score 0):

Solution which worked for me: 
Go into emulator settings, by clicking the three dots on the bottom of the emulator window

go into settings page

change render to "swiftshader"

worked for me!